# Are Star Trek and Devil in the Dark related?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

There was a movie that my friend watched last year called **Devil in the Dark**. I wanted to watch it, but I didn't have time to watch it in the cinemas. I googled *devil in the dark* in images so I know what the cover of the DVD might look like in order to make a purchase at some DVD store and watch the movie, but then I saw pictures of **Star Trek**, particularly the characters Captain Kirk and Mr. Spock.

[image]

The only episode that came to mind in regards to where this image could be from was **The Cloud Minders** since it looks like Kirk and Spock are in a cave, and the episode involves miners (known as *Troglytes*) that dwell in caves. But I don't know how it is related to *Devil in the Dark*.

Are *Star Trek* and *Devil in the Dark* related in any way?

Comment: not sure how googling: "star trek devil in the dark" doesn't immediately answer the question

Comment: @NKCampbell I didn't google "star trek devil in the dark". I googled just "devil in the dark"

Comment: right, and simply adding 'star trek' to the search returns hundreds of results that would answer the question. Seems silly not to have done that. Not worth voting to close, but it's a down vote for me :)

Comment: @NKCampbell I see what you mean. Well, I'm not going to argue with you there. I admit, perhaps I could have done my own research into the matter....

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is an episode called "The Devil in the Dark". From [the Star Trek Wikia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Devil_in_the_Dark_(episode)):

> The Enterprise arrives at Janus VI, where an unknown monster is destroying machinery and killing the miners, threatening the entire mining operation.

The image you've posted is of Spock and Kirk shooting the "Horta", as they don't know its true intentions yet

Comment: They didn’t understand hortaculture...

Comment: @JimGarrison ::initiates slow clap::

Comment: @JimGarrison: = *slap* =

Comment: @JohnBode [Slap Kirk](http://www.slapkirk.com/)? What?

Comment: This comment section is hilarious :D

Comment: But seriously, now you know why directed energy weapons aren't as good as AP KE weapons.

Comment: @JohnBode Hey, I though that up in the '80s while re-watching TOS.  I've been waiting over 30 years for the opportunity to use it :-)  (Also, I'd never heard of Dorothy Parker at that point in my life :-) :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison: I'm mostly mad that I didn't come up with it myself.

Answer (score 6):

There was a movie in 2017 called "Devil in the Dark." There is no connection between that movie and the 1967 Star Trek episode with the same title.

Comment: I knew of the movie, Devil in the Dark. I thought there should have been a connection since I looked up *devil in the dark* in google images and it revealed those star trek photos. That's why I asked the question, in order to clarify.